# How to say Mi Yodeya's version of Echad Mi Yodeya in hebrew

Tags: hebrew, passover-seder-hagada, song-poetry

A selection of the Mi Yodeya series [is being prepared](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3982/11667) for the 
*hagadah mi yodeya*

> 14 are the books of the Rambam.
>   15 were the cubits of the Flood.
>   16 are the maneh of the myrrh.
>   17 were the Yovel cycles.
>   18 are the years before marriage.
>   19 are the years of the calendar.
>   20 is the age of the Draft.
>   21 are the days between the straits.
>   22 are the lines in a mezuzah.
>   23 are the judges of a small high court.
>   24 are the divisions of the kohanim.
>   25 are the letters of Sh'ma.
>   26 is the gematriya of the Tetragrammaton.
>   27 are the letters (including final forms).
>   28 are the "time"s in Koheles.
>   29 is the height of the red line.
>   30 is the age of strength.

The only problem is that this list is in English and I customarily recite the first thirteen in the language as they are found in my regular Hagadah. (Some Hebrew-Aramaic hybrid.)

### So how do I say these ones in Hebrew (in the same Hebrew-Aramaic style as the rest of the song)?

Comment: I feel like this is the type of question that should be closed, but can't think of any specific reason to close...

Answer (score -1):

I will first try transliteration and then use the hebrew keyboard from edit. Obviously someone from Eretz Yisrael would do better.

14 are the books of the Rambam.   - Sifrei Harambam ספרי הרמבם
15 were the cubits of the Flood.  - Ama Milemal'ah (Shel Hamabul)  אַמָּה מִלְמַעְלָה של המבוּל
16 are the maneh of the myrrh. - Mishkal Hamor  (Hei Mem Vav Reish) משקל המור
17 were the Yovel cycles.  - Machzorei hayovelim מחזוֹרי היובלים
18 are the years before marriage. - Shanim lifnei chasunah  שנים לפני חתונה
19 are the years of the calendar. (should be a full cycle) - shnei machzor haluach שני מחזור הלּוּח
20 is the age of the Draft.       - Shnas hatzava  שנת הצבא
21 are the days between the straits. - ymai bain hametzarim ימי בין המצרים
22 are the lines in a mezuzah.        - Shuros hamezuzah  שוּרוֹת המזוּזה
23 are the judges of a small high court. - shoftei sanhedrin hakatan שׁפטי סנהדרין הקטן
24 are the divisions of the kohanim. - Mishnarot hakohanim  משמרות הכהנים
25 are the letters of Sh'ma.            - osyos ha'shma  אוֹתיוֹת השמע
26 is the gematriya of the Tetragrammaton. - gematriah hashem  גמטריא השֵם
27 are the letters (including final forms). - haosyos (kulam)  האוֹתיוֹת כלם
28 are the "time"s in Koheles.     - itei koheles  עִתֵי קוֹהלת
29 is the height of the red line.  - aliyas chut hasikra גובה חוּט הסקרא
30 is the age of strength.         - shnas hako'ach שנת הכח

14 - ארבעה עְשר
15 - חמשה עשר
16 - ששה עשר
17 - שבעה עשר
18 - שמוֹנה עשר
19 - תשעה עשר
20 - עשרים
21 - עשרים וְאחד
22 - עשרים וּשנים
.....
30 - שלוֹשים

Comment: I think the OP wants the numbers too.

Comment: Is this in pure Hebrew or the Hebrew-Aramaic hybrid found in the rest of the song?

Comment: The gender of the numbers should be consistent: ארבעה עשר. Also it seems to me that technically 19 is שנות המחזור הקטן - there are several cycles in the calendar. Also חוט הסקרא - and maybe גובה or מפלס.  I don't think עלייה is very clear. And the best of luck if you want to reach the end before זמן קריאת שמע של שחרית.

Comment: @Epicentre The OP asked for this.

Comment: 24 should be mishmarot.  The Beit av is a seventh of each mishmar who served on a particular day of the week that the mishmar served.